# How to display data in an auto-resizable single-page-fit TILES/GRID/BOX view in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api, rxjs

Can someone please give me an idea on how to display the data fetched from an api in a grid/tiles/box view rather that a tabular view in React.js?

The data should be displayed in boxes/grids/tiles and should resize it self to fit on a single page.
So when more data is added, the boxes need to become smaller in order to fit the single page.

Auto-resizable grid view in React js

[image]